# What happens when compose String with difference sequence?

Tags: java, string

I am confused by below two segments of codes, what makes the difference?

```
    String s1 = new String("1") + new String("2");
    s1.intern();
    String s0 = "12";
    Assert.assertTrue(s1 != s0);
    Assert.assertTrue(s1.equals(s0));

    String s20 = new String("2") + new String("1");
    s20.intern();
    String s21 = "21";
    Assert.assertTrue(s21 == s20);
    Assert.assertTrue(s21.equals(s20));
```

let me explain my question, the above codes pass the test without assert exception, that means "s1 != s0" is true, "s21 == s20" is true as well! "s1 != s0" should be false in my understanding!
if i am not clear, below codes may explain well than my words:

```
    String s20 = new String("2") + new String("1");  // "21"
    s20.intern();
    String s21 = "21";  // "21"
    Assert.assertTrue(s21 == s20);  // equal reference
    Assert.assertTrue(s21.equals(s20));

    s20 = new String("1") + new String("2");  // "12"
    s20.intern();
    s21 = "12";  // "12"
    Assert.assertTrue(s21 != s20);  // NOT equal, why??
    Assert.assertTrue(s21.equals(s20));
```

Comment: `!=` vs, `==`??

Comment: what do you do not undestand, whats the question?

Comment: `intern` returns a new object, you have to write `s20 = s20.intern()`

Comment: This `==` will only be true if `s20` is interned *before* the creation of `s21`

Comment: I modified the question by adding some codes...

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you want but at least you have different comparisons in the assertions:

```
Assert.assertTrue(s1 != s0);
// VS.
Assert.assertTrue(s21 == s20);
```

Comment: You get the difference:  both codes pass the assertion, that's the point I was cofused.

Answer (score 0):

String is an object, not primitif, == or != compare reference and .equals the value.
But you use .intern() but intern() return an String but you can't not assign.